# Material input label is not working properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, material-design, bootstrap-modal

**Im fill data into the model  and it shown like this way.**

[image]

**after click input field display this way.**

[image: after click display this way.]

**this is blade (model-edit-users)**

```
<div class="md-form col-md">
       <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" required>
       <label for="name" class="">User Name</label>
</div>
```

**this is javascript code i used.**

```
$('#users_view_table tbody').on('click', '#editUser', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var data = oTable.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
            var dataname = data.name;

            $("#model-edit-users").modal('show');
            $('#model-edit-users').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
                $('#name').val(dataname);
            });
        });
```

anyone help me to solve this UI issue

Comment: can you try use this
<md-input-container>
        <label>User Name </label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" required>
</md-input-container>

Comment: @user8175473 thank you so much.i tried it two days.thank you for your great idea.

Comment: I created answer, if it worked for you please consider to accept the answer to help people understand question has been solved.

Comment: @user8175473 sorry.thank you again

Comment: your welcome :) There is nothing to say sorry, I just created answer a while ago :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `<md-input-container>` like following

```
<md-input-container> 
  <label>User Name </label> 
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" required> 
</md-input-container>
```